# fill missing value based on index

Tags: python, indexing, missing-data, isnull, fillna

i try to percentace missing value like this

```
null = data.isnull().sum()*100/len(data)
```

and filter like this

```
null_column = null[(null>= 10.0) & (null <= 40.0)].index
```

the output type is index

how can i using *fillna* to replace median in every column based on index

my code before like this

```
null_column = null[(null>= 10.0) & (null <= 40.0)].index
data.fillna(percent_column2.median(), inplace=True)
```

the result always

> index doesnt have median

but when i deleted *index* it works but the median that replaced is not median in every column. But, median that 2 values of percentage missing value not in original dataframe. How can i fill nan value based on index to replace in original data frame?

Comment: Do you want to replace the missing values with the median of the non-missing values?

Comment: `null` is a single value (unless data consists of multiple columns), so creating `null_column` is going wrong I think.

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar no, I'm not trying to make it column, i just want to replace nan value with median on column that refer to `null[(null>= 10.0) & (null <= 40.0)].index` but the result always index doesn't have median

Comment: can you give a simple example of your input and desired output?

Comment: if i use this `null = data.isnull().sum()*100/len(data)` the output would be column that have percentage missing value, but i need only around 10 to 40 percent so i using this `null[(null>= 10.0) & (null <= 40.0)].index` so i get 2 column like this `Index(['times_pregnant', 'tricep_skin_fold_thickness'], dtype='object')` and i want to replace that column which is have nan value with median so i use `data.fillna(percent_column2.median(), inplace=True)` but the result is index doesn't have median. My desired output is 2 that colum can replaced with median in every that column. @TobiasMolenaar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess something like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,np.nan],[np.nan,1,np.nan],[1,np.nan,2],[23,12,3],[1,3,1]])
cols = list(null[(null>=10) & (null<=40)].index)
data.iloc[:, cols] = data.iloc[:, cols].fillna(data.iloc[:, cols].median(), inplace=False)
```